# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') - Gravity Forms WP

Tags: elementor, gravity-forms-plugin, wordpress-shortcode

```
jquery.textareaCounter.plugin.js?ver=2.8.6:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at charCounters.standard (jquery.textareaCounter.plugin.js?ver=2.8.6:31:22)
    at countByCharacters (jquery.textareaCounter.plugin.js?ver=2.8.6:115:27)
    at limitTextAreaByCharacterCount (jquery.textareaCounter.plugin.js?ver=2.8.6:172:25)
    at $.fn.textareaCount (jquery.textareaCounter.plugin.js?ver=2.8.6:185:5)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):2372:1350)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=3.7.1:5145:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js?ver=3.7.1:4949:28)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=3.7.1:8629:12)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=3.7.1:8707:17)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=3.7.1:383:19)
```

Gravity Forms Version 2.8.6

Elementor Version 3.20.2

When I am adding Gravity Forms in Elementor pop-up, I got this Error.

Error File : /wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/jquery.textareaCounter.plugin.js